# Update a date/time field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM vtiger_crmentity WHERE orderdetailsid=" . $orderdetailsid;
            $query2 = "UPDATE vtiger_crmentity SET createdtime=NOW(),modifiedtime=NOW(),viewedtime=NOW() WHERE orderdetailsid=" . $orderdetailsid;

                $result1 = mysql_query($query1); echo mysql_error();
                $result2 = mysql_query($query2); echo mysql_error();
```

Doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Have you verified `$orderdetailsid` has a valid value?

Comment: Are you quoting correctly? (you missed the first part so I can't tell): `$query = "UPDATE vtiger_crmentity SET createdtime=NOW(),modifiedtime=NOW(),viewedtime=NOW() WHERE orderdetailsid=" . $orderdetailsid;`

Comment: Sorry just skipped the $query =. It just doesn't insert, stays at 00-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Yes $orderdetailsid is valid. Is my NOW() just not correct or? Oh and yes those are set to date in mysql

Answer (score 1):

1>check the database field type of those 3 fields createdtime,modifiedtime,viewedtime.

2>check $orderdetailsid has a proper value or not ,if $orderdetailsid has proper value then with check with that value is there any record present in database or not

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the orderdetailsid column to the vtiger_crmentity table? By default, that table does not contain *orderdetailsid*, the only id in that table is *crmid*. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score -3):

First try writing correct mysql queries; if it still doesn't work you can always use php to insert the current date/time. Something like :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `vtiger_crmentity` SET `createdtime` = '" . time() . "' , `modifiedtime` = '" . time() . "', `viewedtime` = '" . time() . "' WHERE `orderdetailsid` = '" . $orderdetailsid ."'");
```